# C # application for linux?

Tags: c#, linux

Is there a way to develop Linux applications with C # with a graphical interface? That is to say with a window buttons and such things, I have tried it with .net core but apparently it is just for console applications.

Comment: Related: [Can WPF applications be run in Linux with .Net Core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53954047/1441)

Comment: https://docs.cs.cf.ac.uk/notes/connecting-to-the-linux-gui-remotely/

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/picoe/Eto - and then at _search engines_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look for writing c# code on linux you will probably run into http://www.mono-project.com/.

This is what you find on Mono's page :
"Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. A growing family of solutions and an active and enthusiastic contributing community is helping position Mono to become the leading choice for development of cross platform applications."

Both Mono and .NET Core support GNU/Linux systems like Ubuntu.

.NET Core is available on different Linux distributions. You will learn more about it on Microsoft's documentation site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux

Editors like Gedit Vim have syntax for C#.
MonoDevelop and Visual Studio Code are two environments which  run on Ubuntu and support C# development.

Additionally I recommend this site , if you want to learn more about developing apps for Linux:
https://teckangaroo.com/c-sharp-linux/