# Develop WPF Application using .NET Core on VS for Mac

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-core

Can I develop a WPF application to install on Windows machine using Visual Studio for Mac with .NET Core?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can WPF applications be run in Linux or Mac with .Net Core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954047/can-wpf-applications-be-run-in-linux-or-mac-with-net-core-3)

Answer (score 3):

No.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2019-compatibility-mac#platform-targeting

"Visual Studio for Mac does not support Windows client projects like Windows Forms, WPF, or UWP."

You can develop xamarin or unity but no wpf.