# Compiling c# in linux using mcs compiler gives error : The type or namespace name `Forms' does not exist in the namespace `System.Windows'?

Tags: c#, linux, compiler-errors, mono

I am trying to compile some c# code in linux, i can compile the same code in Windows using the csc command in Visual Studio command line. I also have already installed mono-devel.

this is the exact error :

```
mycode.cs(8,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Forms' does not exist in the namespace `System.Windows'. Are you missing `System.Windows.Forms' assembly reference?

mycode.cs(70,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Form' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

this is the command I'm using to compile it in linux :

```
mcs mycode.cs
```

and inside the code, Windows forms is already included :

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

also simple hello world code does get compiled without any error, i basically followed this blogpost about how to compile c# code in linux to set everything up :

https://jonsson.xyz/2016/11/23/csharp-linux/

Comment: Which version of .net? Desktop forms wasn't introduced 
too the new .net until .net core 3.1 I think (you can check it online)

Comment: @ADyson I'm not sure, i only installed mono-devel in linux as suggested here :  https://jonsson.xyz/2016/11/23/csharp-linux.  the code was also given to me and I didn't write it, but its not that complicated of a code, only like 300-400 lines of code.

Comment: @ADyson also simple hello world code does get compiled without any error

Comment: What is Turbo C# ? ._.

Comment: @arrowd the manual of mcs command says its "Turbo C# Compiler", although I'm not sure what this is I'm not really familiar with compiling c# code in linux, i just followed this :  https://jonsson.xyz/2016/11/23/csharp-linux/

Comment: Mono is a bit legacy now and won't get support for forms. Firms was windows-only until very recently. Use the new .NET 5 with visual studio code as your IDE, would be my recommendation.

Comment: Actually though sorry I'm not quite correct. Forms were added to .net core and then .net 5 but they are still windows only. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954915/5947043

Comment: This is coming, but probably not soon enough for you: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/

Comment: This might be more like what you need at the moment: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/develop-cross-platform-net-core-desktop-apps-on-linux-with-xaml-bf3dbba9afa0

Comment: @ADyson so basically right now there is no simple tool that i can just get using apt get and compile c# codes with windows forms, correct?

Comment: No and there never will be. You can use c# but you need to use a different tool to build the user interface, you can't use the Windows Forms library unless you are running Windows.

Comment: The blog post you followed shows a simple console application, so it is no proof that you might use WinForms there. Don’t waste your time and stick to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling with `-r:System.Windows.Forms.dll` ?

for example:

wc.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var f = new Form();
        f.Text = "Hello World";
        Application.Run(f);
    }
}
```

then run:
`$ mono-csc wf.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll`
and you get `wf.exe`

Comment: When I tried this I got more errors:
error CS0103: The name `InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
as well as the other variables that used forms that were in the code.

Comment: were you able to compile the example program I gave? you probably need to add more references to . DLLs