# How to build cross platform gui app using dot net core?

Tags: .net-core

Is it possible to develop cross platform GUI desktop application using .net core?? I tried searching, but I think u can only build cross platform console app

Comment: There are cross platform UI libraries, such as https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia...

Comment: you could hang around and wait for [MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/).

Comment: Andy and omajid is right, btw here is a related question with a lot of answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954047/can-wpf-applications-be-run-in-linux-with-net-core-3

Comment: This is a little imprecise, do you require it to load directly in the OS? If you are happy for it to operate in a browser, then you can create a .Net Core Asp.net type solution