# Make multiplatform application for mac os from windows environment using WPF .Net.Core

Tags: c#, wpf, macos, .net-core, multiplatform

I want to make a multiplatform application from windows environment for macOS. I want to know how to configure the 'csproj' file.

My .csproj file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> <!-- How to put executable for macOS -->
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers> 
    <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You cannot target macOS with WPF projects: WPF only supports Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954047/can-wpf-applications-be-run-in-linux-or-mac-with-net-core-3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can WPF applications be run in Linux or Mac with .Net Core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954047/can-wpf-applications-be-run-in-linux-or-mac-with-net-core-3)

Comment: Consider switching to MAUI - https://github.com/dotnet/maui